# Tcp Throughput Graph

Tags: tcp

I have created a TCP client/server chat software on console in vb.net..m using local host for this program means packets send and receive from the same network interface card..
now i captured packets from this software on Wireshark..and i want to plot TCp throughput graph from the data captured on wireshark but i am having problem with this..kindly help me..!
Also teach me which value should be taken on x and y axis..?

here is the data i captured on wireshark as i can't distinguished between sent and received pckets..!

```
No.,"Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Info","New Column","New Column"
1,"0.000000","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","pda-data > versiera [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65510 Len=3","1","9050"


2,"0.441512","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Retransmission] pda-data > versiera [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65510 Len=3","2","9050"


3,"0.442643","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","versiera > pda-data [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4 Win=65532 Len=3","3","3253"

4,"0.829213","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Retransmission] versiera > pda-data [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4 Win=65532 Len=3","4","3253"

5,"0.949875","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","pda-data > versiera [ACK] Seq=4 Ack=4 Win=65507 Len=0","5","9050"

6,"1.259930","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Dup ACK 5#1] pda-data > versiera [ACK] Seq=4 Ack=4 Win=65507 Len=0","6","9050"

7,"6.755535","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","pda-data > versiera [PSH, ACK] Seq=4 Ack=4 Win=65507 Len=3","7","9050"

8,"7.119189","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Retransmission] pda-data > versiera [PSH, ACK] Seq=4 Ack=4 Win=65507 Len=3","8","9050"

9,"7.119833","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","versiera > pda-data [PSH, ACK] Seq=4 Ack=7 Win=65529 Len=3","9","3253"

10,"7.467483","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Retransmission] versiera > pda-data [PSH, ACK] Seq=4 Ack=7 Win=65529 Len=3","10","3253"

11,"7.588601","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","pda-data > versiera [ACK] Seq=7 Ack=7 Win=65504 Len=0","11","9050"

12,"7.931341","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Dup ACK 11#1] pda-data > versiera [ACK] Seq=7 Ack=7 Win=65504 Len=0","12","9050"

13,"11.311228","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","pda-data > versiera [PSH, ACK] Seq=7 Ack=7 Win=65504 Len=3","13","9050"

14,"11.650297","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Retransmission] pda-data > versiera [PSH, ACK] Seq=7 Ack=7 Win=65504 Len=3","14","9050"

15,"11.650931","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","versiera > pda-data [PSH, ACK] Seq=7 Ack=10 Win=65526 Len=3","15","3253"

16,"11.953358","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Retransmission] versiera > pda-data [PSH, ACK] Seq=7 Ack=10 Win=65526 Len=3","16","3253"

17,"12.114983","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","pda-data > versiera [ACK] Seq=10 Ack=10 Win=65501 Len=0","17","9050"

18,"12.388906","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Dup ACK 17#1] pda-data > versiera [ACK] Seq=10 Ack=10 Win=65501 Len=0","18","9050"

19,"18.455431","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","pda-data > versiera [PSH, ACK] Seq=10 Ack=10 Win=65501 Len=3","19","9050"

20,"18.699858","115.186.111.66","115.186.111.66","TCP","[TCP Retransmission] pda-data > versiera [PSH, ACK] Seq=10 Ack=10 Win=65501 Len=3","20","9050"
```

Sorry i can't find a better way than this to post here my wirehsrak data :-O

Comment: If you want to graph throughput, it's a fair bet that one of the axes is going to be "throughput"...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are monitoring a conversation between your PC and itself, yes, that would make it hard.  Generally if you are the source, then You were sending, if you are the destination then you are receiving.

I would suggest X axis is time, Y axis is throughput.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard.  You should be able to identify client and server by matching the TCP port numbers reported by wireshark.

Comment: But i am using same (9050) port in both my programs..do you want me to change anyone of them and then captured packtes?

Comment: No, but, it is more confusing than if you have 2 test machines to verify your thoughts as why would you monitor the traffic talking to yourself? as technically it never leaves.  The port numbers help, but normally you would be looking at 2 different machines surely?

Comment: @ bug finder:
x-axis is time makes sense to me ..but there is no such thing namely throughput in my wireshark data as shown in my question :-(

Comment: @Madiha: You're using the same IP address *and* TCP port for both ends of the connection?  How does that work?

Comment: The "sending" port is generally random. For example, do a "netstat -an" on your PC while webbing, you will see external connections to port 80 on websites, but your box will not be using port 80 to connect out, it assigns a random port.

Comment: Hmm..rite.. so now i'll try monitor the traffic on two different machines..!

Comment: @Madiha, sure there is, quantity per second is your throughput, even if only counting messages let alone physical data size.

Comment: @ Oli
Yea i am Using same pc as client and server.. i heard from one of my teacher that it is possible to monitor traffic using a single machine..

Comment: You can, but as he said, and I explained, you need to be awake and watch port numbers, as for example, incoming data on port 9050 would be received and from another port to port 9050 would be sent, but because you have 2 apps trying to do the same thing on the same box, like Oli, I find it hard to see how both apps took control of the same port on the same IP. If you watch 2 different machines talk, the output of wireshark should be easier for you to understand and then maybe apply to the 1 machine talking to itself log